# Webpack importing files without extension outputs changes incorrectly in HMR(Hot Module Replacement)

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement

I follow this [guide](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hot-module-replacement/) and write code like that guide. Everything is Ok! But when I change `import printMe from './print.js'` to `import printMe from './print'`, HMR doesn't output changes correctly!

When I change like following in `print.js`:

```
   export default function printMe() {
 -   console.log('I get called from print.js!');
 +   console.log('Updating print.js...')
   }
```

Console should output: Updating print.js...

But it outputs: I get called from print.js!

When I sencond change 'Updating print.js...' to 'Updating print.js again...', it doesn't out changes.

The following is my snapshot:

[image: console output]

However, [Module Resolution](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/module-resolution/) says:

> - If the path has a file extension, then the file is bundled straightaway.
> - Otherwise, the file extension is resolved using the resolve.extensions option, which tells the resolver which extensions (eg - .js, .jsx) are acceptable for resolution.

and [resolve-extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions) also says:

> Automatically resolve certain extensions. This defaults to:
>
> ```
> extensions: [".js", ".json"]
> ```

**So, my question is: Can't webpack resolve the path without extension like what it says above? Is this a bug or what I am doing wrong?** What I have done is just changing `import printMe from './print.js'` to `import printMe from './print'`.

My environment:

- node v7.4.0
- npm 4.0.5
- webpack 3.4.1
- webpack-dev-server 2.6.1
- macOS Sierra 10.12

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose I know why it works incorrectly.

What I do is:

**src/index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print';

// ...

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    printMe();
  });
}
```

But you should always make the name of `import` and the first param of `module.hot.accept` be the same:

**src/index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print';

// ...

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    printMe();
  });
}
```

**OR:**

**src/index.js**

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import printMe from './print.js';

// ...

if(module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept('./print.js', function() {
    console.log('Accepting the updated printMe module!');
    printMe();
  });
}
```

These two situations all work. It may be the expected behaviour of authors of webpack. But from my points of view they three situations should all have worked. :(